# TypeHeadBootStrap does not work

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I have a JSON which has the following structure:

`[{"id":1,"nome":"teste"},{"id":2,"nome":"teste"},{"id":3,"nome":"teste3"}]`

I want to use it this head type code but however it does not load, In the browser console shows that loaded the `json` correctly.

```
$('#nome').typeahead({
    source: function(query, process) {
        objects = [];
        map = {};
        console.log(data);
        $.each(data, function(i, object) {
            map[object.label] = object;
            objects.push(object.label);
        });
        process(objects);
    },
    updater: function(item) {
        console.log(map[item].id);
        //$('hiddenInputElement').val(map[item].id);
        return item;
    }
});
```

I am using this lib: https://github.com/bassjobsen/Bootstrap-3-Typeahead

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved changed library for this https://github.com/biggora/bootstrap-ajax-typeahead